# Finding the number of documents in a Lucene index

Tags: java, lucene

Using the Java version of Lucene, how would you find out the number of documents in an index?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IndexReader contains the methods you need, in particular, numDocs

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#numDocs()

Comment: The link no longer works, but a more recent document exists here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#numDocs()

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#numDocs()

Answer (score 3):

Using java you can find the number of documents like this :

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory));
System.out.println(reader.maxDoc()); //this will give ya what you need.
```

Comment: Technically, this will include the documents that have been deleted. `reader.numDocs()` takes this into account.

Answer (score 1):

With recent Lucene version using an [IndexReader](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0//core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html) the following Kotlin snippet does the job:

```kotlin
DirectoryReader.open(directory).use { reader ->
    println(reader.numDocs())
}
```

where `directory` is an instance of [Directory](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0//core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) containing the index.

Answer (score 0):

When using Hibernate Search, it is possible to obtain a Lucene `IndexReader` instance through the Hibernate Search API and then use `reader.numDocs()` as already mentioned in previous answers.

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(get‌​EntityManager());
IndexReader reader = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().getIndexReaderAcces‌​sor().open(MyEntity1‌​.class, MyEntity2.class ...);
int numDocs = reader.numDocs();
```