# How to get total count of document in lucene

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have very large number of documents in my index, I need to write a method that return total number of documents in the lucence index. Currently I used * wild card to fetch all the records and return the value of totalHits.

Problem is that as the query loads all object it is taking lot of time although I don't need object to be loaded just my requirement is to get total number of records without loading the documents.

Comment: I think this post answers what you are look for:
[Finding the number of documents in a lucene index][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442463/finding-the-number-of-documents-in-a-lucene-index

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the index reader:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory));
int num = reader.numDocs();
```

Omri