# Neo4j labels and how to speed up counting labelled nodes?

Tags: neo4j, indexing, label

`Neo4j` has introduced `labels` as of version `2.0`. From their own explanations of the feature, labels are meant to group nodes into named sets.

I've been playing with that option, and it seems like there's no way to tell `how many nodes are labelled with Foo` other than doing:

`match n:Foo return count(n);`

The problem is that on large sets, this operation is very slow. For example, on my database with `640K` nodes labelled with '`Foo`, the query runs for about 50 seconds.

I would expect that labels would bring some performance improvement over properties by default, but they don't seem to do so. So I wonder if there's a way to speed up the calculation of the size of the labelled set? With some `Gremlin` magic, maybe?

And a related question: are labels in `Neo4j` indexed, or are they similar to any other non-indexed properties by default, in terms of filtering speed?

Comment: it will be faster in the next milestones of 2.0, currently this is still a full scan, but don't derive any performance conclusions from the current, early milestones

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find any API in Neo4j for this, below is one way to do it.

Neo4j creates a independent index for each of the label types. Each of the created index is a [full Lucene index](http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/03/15/a-peek-behind-the-neo4j-lucene-index-curtain/). Since it is a Lucene index, you can open the index in *Read Only* mode using Lucence API and use [its numDocs method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442463/finding-the-number-of-documents-in-a-lucene-index).

**Opening in read-only mode is very important.**

Comment: Is 'opening a Lucene index in read-only mode' something accessible via their Java API (and, thus, via Gremlin)? I understand that they have to have this data somewhere internally, being it a Lucene index or anything else, the question is whether I can use this information using their API/plugins.